# CK Editor not displaying \n content in New line

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor

I have an ASP.NET Page where I integrated CKEditor to show the rich text content.
The ckeditor on my page just not shows the \n new line character from Database. i.e. for example
My Database have the following in it.

```
....................................................
12/9/2014 12:17:36 PM U.S. AZ (UTC/GMT -7), USER,A:  (New)
Description: passes checks and gas

'ABC' IS CHANGED FROM 'Issues Found' TO 'Needs Check'
'Lib Check 2' IS CHANGED FROM 'Issues Found' TO 'Passed Checks - Released To None Lib'

....................................................
12/8/2014 10:29:41 AM U.S. AZ (UTC/GMT -7), USER,B:  (New)
Description: 

'DEF' IS CHANGED FROM 'K' TO 'Submitted: Assigned'
'Logic Status' IS CHANGED FROM 'Submitted: Not Assigned' TO 'Submitted: Assigned'
'Platform' IS CHANGED FROM 'Purley' TO 'Purley'

....................................................
12/5/2014 2:21:48 PM U.S. AZ (UTC/GMT -7), USER ,C:  (New)
Description: please recheck, I found an issue
```

Now I expect CKEditor to display as it was in DB. but it displays the above text as follows

> `....................................................12/9/2014 12:17:36 PM U.S. AZ (UTC/GMT -7), USER,A:  (New)Description: passes checks and gas'ABC' IS CHANGED FROM 'Issues Found' TO 'Needs Check''Lib Check 2' IS CHANGED FROM 'Issues Found' TO 'Passed Checks - Released To None Lib'....................................................12/8/2014 10:29:41 AM U.S. AZ (UTC/GMT -7), USER,B:  (New)Description: 'DEF' IS CHANGED FROM 'K' TO 'Submitted: Assigned''Logic Status' IS CHANGED FROM 'Submitted: Not Assigned' TO 'Submitted: Assigned''Platform' IS CHANGED FROM Purley'TOPurley'....................................................12/5/2014 2:21:48 PM U.S. AZ (UTC/GMT -7), USER ,C:  (New)
>   Description: please recheck, I found an issue`

As you can see, CKEditor is not obeying the formatting. not sure which setting in Config solves my problem. Here is my config.js file. I am tired of trying different config option but none worked.

```
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.removePlugins = 'toolbar,elementspath,resize';
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.ignoreEmptyParagraph = true;
    config.entities = false;
    config.basicEntities = false;
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    config.extraPlugins = 'htmlwriter';
};

CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
         ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.indentationChars = '\t';
         ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.selfClosingEnd = ' />';
         ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.lineBreakChars = '\n';
});
```

Comment: You're displaying in a web browser. unless that text is surrouned by `<pre>`, then line breaks are treated as spaces. either use `<pre>`, or convert `\n` to `<br>`

Comment: Is there any config setting that we can do in config.js that can enclose all the CKEditor content in pre before anything is displayed on Page or assigned to CKEditor.